# Order of element in group given by order of conjugacy class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> What is the order of $x$ in a group of order 21 that contains a conjugacy class of order 3?

I know the answer is 7 because the size of the conjugacy class of $x$ equals the index of its centralizer: $[G:Z(x)]$. However, why is the order of the element equal to the cardinality of the centralizer?

Comment: In general, it's not!  (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\langle x\rangle$ is certainly a subgroup of its centralizer $Z(x)$ (which does have order 7) and a group of order $7$ can have only one proper subgroup.  If $x=1$, then its class size would be $1$, because the centralizer of $1$ is the entire group.